# Applying Transformations to Live Camera Feed using Picamera2 and QGlPicamera2

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a camera script for a raspberry pi 4. I'm using bullseye 64 bit with pi camera module 3 so the new picamera2 library is required.  I'm trying to implement a symmetric mirror image effect where the image is cut in horizontally, and then then that half is flipped and mirrored. I've got a demo working using QLabel as a container for the camera feed, but I'm wondering if it would be possible to do this with the QGlPicamera2 widget?  Since the video is GPU accelerated it should have better performance, and I also am working on integrated this capture method into a more complex camera script I'm working on that is using QGlPicamera2 instead of QLabel.  The manual does have a section on display overlays using transparent png or similar but this seems to be mainly for applying a watermark type effect to video.  There are also some demos of applying face detection boxes to live video feed which isn't what I'm looking for but shows that there is some flexibility with drawing dynamic effects on top of a live video feed with the QGlPicamera2 widget.

Here's the working code snippet using Qlabel:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from libcamera import controls
import io

class CameraApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Initialize Picamera2
        self.picam2 = Picamera2()
        config = self.picam2.create_preview_configuration(main={"size": (800, 480)})
        self.picam2.configure(config)

        # Enable autofocus
        self.picam2.set_controls({"AfMode": controls.AfModeEnum.Continuous})

        # Start the camera
        self.picam2.start()

        # Create a label to display the camera feed
        self.camera_label = QLabel(self)
        self.camera_label.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 480)

        # Create a button to toggle the mirror effect
        self.toggle_button = QPushButton("Toggle Mirror Effect", self)
        self.toggle_button.setGeometry(600, 430, 200, 50)
        self.toggle_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 18px;")

        # Create a close button
        self.close_button = QPushButton("Close", self)
        self.close_button.setGeometry(700, 10, 90, 40)
        self.close_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: red; color: white; font-size: 18px;")
        
        # Create opacity effect for toggle button
        toggle_opacity_effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(self.toggle_button)
        toggle_opacity_effect.setOpacity(0.7)
        self.toggle_button.setGraphicsEffect(toggle_opacity_effect)

        # Connect the button to the toggle function
        self.toggle_button.clicked.connect(self.toggle_mirror_effect)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.close_application)

        # Flag to keep track of the mirror effect state
        self.mirror_effect = False

        # Create a QTimer to update the camera feed
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_camera_feed)
        self.timer.start(30)  # Update the feed every 30 ms

        # Set full screen
        self.showFullScreen()

    def toggle_mirror_effect(self):
        """
        Toggle the mirror effect on or off.
        """
        self.mirror_effect = not self.mirror_effect

    def close_application(self):
        """
        Close the application.
        """
        self.timer.stop()  # Stop the QTimer
        self.picam2.stop()  # Stop the camera
        QApplication.quit()  # Close the application

    def update_camera_feed(self):
        """
        Update the camera label with the live feed from the camera, applying the mirror effect if needed.
        """
        # Capture the frame from the camera
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        self.picam2.capture_file(stream, format='jpeg')  # Specify the format explicitly
        stream.seek(0)
        frame = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(stream.getvalue(), np.uint8), 1)

        # Convert color space from BGR to RGB
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        if self.mirror_effect:
            # Apply the mirror effect
            mid_x = frame.shape[1] // 2
            left_half = frame[:, :mid_x]
            right_half = cv2.flip(left_half, 1)
            frame = np.concatenate((left_half, right_half), axis=1)

        # Convert the frame to QImage and display it on the QLabel
        height, width, channel = frame.shape
        bytes_per_line = 3 * width
        q_image = QImage(frame.data, width, height, bytes_per_line, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.camera_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(q_image))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.timer.stop()  # Stop the QTimer
        self.picam2.stop()  # Stop the camera
        event.accept()

# Run the application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = CameraApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The manual for picamera2 library is here: https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/camera/picamera2-manual.pdf

I've searched around for examples of anyone working with experimental effects but it seems picamera2 library is too new for there to be many examples.  I may have some other fun effects I like to apply to the live feed so if there's a method out there that would retain GPU accelerated video rendering with effects applied on top of it, that would be fantastic!